# Connection Reset

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I am using sql server database, jtds driver and java1.6.0_16.

In my client code, i want to execute number of query(Stored procedure) and write data into a file.
First query executed successfully and write into a file.
Second query executed successfully and while iterating from result set object, it thrown exception **"java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset"**

```
**Below is the Full Stack Trace :**

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2277)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:761)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next(JtdsResultSet.java:593)
 ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:860)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:707)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:466)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:103)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.readInt(ResponseStream.java:320)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsData.readData(TdsData.java:652)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsRowToken(TdsCore.java:2968)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2236)
```

Please Note : While using java 1.5 it works successfully without any issue.The error occurred while using java 1.6.0_16.Google does not help me.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Ganesan